# Is "colegiala" a type of flower?

Tags: vocabulario, definiciones, colombia

A native speaker in Colombia showed me a flower and told me it was called a *colegiala*, but the only translation I can find is schoolgirl or female college student. Also, I haven't been able to find any reference to this type of flower online.

Can anyone verify that *colegiala* is also a flower?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems it's actually the name of a flower, although to be honest, this is the first time I heard about it (not that I'm particularly good at plants). It must be a local name.

I could find this link with a picture of the flower attached to it:

http://www.infojardin.com/foro/showthread.php?t=299647

[image: Picture of the _Colegiala_ in case the link goes bad]

If someone could identify the plant and find its scientific name, we could perhaps contribute a myriad of other local names.

UPDATE: A bit of further research gave me the names *Bignonia Rosea* and *Fridericia chica*, but as I said, I'm not exactly an authority in plants. Someone should verify that the plant above is actually the species mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, COLEGIALA is normally used to make reference to girl who's in Junior or High School(bachillerato), overall when she is wearing her uniform. I have to say it's a very formal way to say it. You could hear from someone to say: ALLÍ VA LA COLEGIALA CAMINANDO CON SUS LIBROS HACIA EL LICEO. It happens that in different LAT countries you can find the same plant but with a different name, usually this happens with flower-plants, so at the end, that name, colegiala, must be the popular name for that plant in Colombia, it's probable in other countries nearby, you could find the same plant but with a different local name! BTW the most common expression for COLEGIALA is: LA ESTUDIANTE.